# jQuery check if checkbox is unchecked not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I got some problem while checking checkbox, it always return true, didn't work in the false statement, I want to stop before click the add button if none of the checkbox is checked. How to fix it?

Here's my code:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
 var weekDays = [];
 $('#checkBox :checked').each(function () {
  weekDays.push($(this).attr('name'));
 });
 
    var row = '<tr>'
   + '<td class="rowDays">' + weekDays + '</td>'
   + '</tr>';
 
    if (!$("#days").find("checkbox").is(":checked")) {
     $(row).insertAfter($('#days > tbody > tr:last'));
 } else{
     alert('unchecked!')
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="checkBox">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th>Sun</th>
   <th>Mon</th>
   <th>Tue</th>
   <th>Wed</th>
   <th>Thu</th>
   <th>Fri</th>
   <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input name="Sunday" type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
   <td><input name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
   <td><input name="Tuesday" type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
   <td><input name="Wednesday" type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
   <td><input name="Thursday" type="checkbox" value="4"></td>
   <td><input name="Friday" type="checkbox" value="5"></td>
   <td><input name="Saturday" type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
            
<button type="button" class="add">Add Days</button>
<br>
<br>
<table id="days">
    <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Days</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppf2qe4u/1/)

Comment: [is this what you're trying to do?](https://jsfiddle.net/ppf2qe4u/5/)

Comment: @billyonecan Yes! That's what I need! Could you please answer this question? So I can accept your answer. Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect `$("#days").find("checkbox")` will not find anything (`#days` doesn't have any checkboxes, and `checkbox` isn't a valid selector for retrieving checkboxes).

You just need to test check the length of the checked checkboxes in `#checkBox`:

```
if (! $('#checkBox :checked').length ) {
    return false;
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
$('.add').click(function() {

    if (! $('#checkBox :checked').length ) {
        return false;   
    }

    var weekDays = $('#checkBox :checked').map(function() { 
        return this.name;
    }).get();

    var row = '<tr>'
            + '<td class="rowDays">' + weekDays.join(', ') + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';

    $(row).appendTo('#days > tbody');

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppf2qe4u/5/)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

1) Set a common class (Ex: myCheckbox) to each input as :

```
<input class="myCheckbox" name="Sunday" type="checkbox" value="0">
```

2) Get all input which have this class and which is 'checked'

3) Use the 'length' property as :

```
if ($("input[class=myCheckbox]:checked").length > 0) {
    $(row).insertAfter($('#days > tbody > tr:last'));
} else{
    alert('unchecked!')
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but why can't I add when I checked the checkbox?

Comment: because `$("#days").find("checkbox:checked").length` will never be `> 0` (the selector is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#days").find("checkbox").is(":checked").length!=0) {
        $(row).insertAfter($('#days > tbody > tr:last'));
} else{
        alert('unchecked!')
        return false;
}
```

Use `$("#days").find("checkbox").is(":checked").length` to calculate the number of checked elemented and then compare it with 0.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/ppf2qe4u/10/)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, yeah true. I just read it ` I want to stop before click the add button if none of the checkbox is checked. How to fix it?` sorry my bad. See updated answer.

Comment: Yep fixed now, comments removed

Comment: I tried the code but why can't I add when I checked the checkbox?